# Realm database close for writing from an extension

Tags: ios, realm

So I'm trying hard track down why a Realm db can't be written to from an iOS share extension reliably. I'd like to be able to update my realm db from the extension, and then allow my containing app to reload the db after the extension is through with it. It stays pretty small, as most of the stuff I do I keep in cloudkit. I use realm as a kind of index of the data for the UI.

is there a way to invalidate or close or release or whatever my containning app's instance of Realm, so that is can be safely written to by my extension? I was thinking of doing that "close" of the db on "applicationBecameInactive"

would that work??

it works sometimes as I have set it up now, mostly, and sometimes it dumps...

and here is an edited version of the dump, when is does fail....

```
alloc_slab.cpp:494: [realm-core-0.94.0] Assertion failed: cfg.session_initiator || !cfg.is_shared [0, 0]
0  Realm                              0x00335787 _ZN5realm4util18terminate_internalERNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 86
1  Realm                              0x0045e8a3 _ZN5realm4util9terminateIbJbEEEvPKcS3_lT_DpT0_ + 602
2  Realm                              0x0033806d _ZN5realm9SlabAlloc11attach_fileERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEERNS0_6ConfigE + 2056
3  Realm                              0x003e2ec9 _ZN5realm11SharedGroup9do_open_2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbNS0_15DurabilityLevelEbPKc + 832
4  Realm                              0x003e2a33 _ZN5realm11SharedGroup9do_open_1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEEbNS0_15DurabilityLevelEbPKcb + 46
5  Realm                              0x003206dd _ZNSt3__113__vector_baseIPN5realm5TableENS_9allocatorIS3_EEED2Ev + 640
6  Realm                              0x0031a199 RLMRealmAddPathSettingsToConfiguration + 2136
7  Realm                              0x0031b303 RLMRealmAddPathSettingsToConfiguration + 6594
8  RealmSwift                          0x0056eee8 _TFC10RealmSwift5RealmCfMS0_FzT13configurationVS0_13Configuration_S0_ + 904
9  SaveToTioga                        0x00113260 SaveToTioga + 156256
10  SaveToTioga                        0x001135d0 SaveToTioga + 157136
11  SaveToTioga                        0x00113914 SaveToTioga + 157972
12  SaveToTioga                        0x00105bf4 SaveToTioga + 101364
13  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib            0x00ab1a0c _TF10ObjectiveC15autoreleasepoolFFT_T_T_ + 40
14  SaveToTioga                        0x00105078 SaveToTioga + 98424
15  SaveToTioga                        0x001024f8 SaveToTioga + 87288
16  SaveToTioga                        0x0013a1e0 SaveToTioga + 315872
17  SaveToTioga                        0x00132760 SaveToTioga + 284512
18  SaveToTioga                        0x001035dc SaveToTioga + 91612
19  libdispatch.dylib                  0x38f13e2f <redacted> + 10
20  libdispatch.dylib                  0x38f13e1b <redacted> + 22
21  libdispatch.dylib                  0x38f186c9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1532
22  CoreFoundation                      0x26d6c535 <redacted> + 8
23  CoreFoundation                      0x26d6aa2f <redacted> + 1590
24  CoreFoundation                      0x26cbd0d9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
25  CoreFoundation                      0x26cbcecd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
26  GraphicsServices                    0x2fea4af9 GSEventRunModal + 160
27  UIKit                              0x2af462dd UIApplicationMain + 144
28  libxpc.dylib                        0x390d01db <redacted> + 706
29  libxpc.dylib                        0x390d1855 xpc_main + 168
30  Foundation                          0x27c56c51 <redacted> + 0
31  PlugInKit                          0x32a3e181 <redacted> + 508
32  PlugInKit                          0x32a3de4f <redacted> + 58
33  PlugInKit                          0x32a3e1b5 <redacted> + 20
34  libextension.dylib                  0x3813f7cd NSExtensionMain + 48
35  libdyld.dylib                      0x38f3c873 <redacted> + 2
IMPORTANT: if you see this error, please send this log to help@realm.io.
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? How do you setup the path for your Realm?

Comment: I actully put the realm into  shared group that I've setup. I mean to emphasize, it does work sometimes, but not always. Sometimes it throws a long dump... I'm working to capture the actual dump... see above...

Comment: What you report here seems to be a bug, which seems similar to [these reports here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2841). Do you make use of encryption as well?

Comment: I don't use encryption, and the db is only about 15KB. Thanks for the link above, I'll monitor things there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the database from multiple process at once, there are mechanisms in place which ensure that this is handled correctly. So it shouldn't be necessary to close the database, which is only possible by making sure that you don't retain any `RLMRealm`, `RLMObject` and `RLMResults` instances.

You're hitting here a [crash](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2841), as linked before in the comments, which was recently brought to our attention and <del>we're still actively investigating</del> we could fix meanwhile and ship with version 0.96.3.